# Initialise moment.js with UTC datetime value

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, datetime, momentjs, utc

In my application, all datetimes are stored in the database in UTC. These dates are then converted to the correct timezone when the server-side code renders HTML.

I am, however, having problems rendering UTC datetimes in client-side JavaScript using moment.js to convert them to the local timezone.

In the example below, the UTC date stored in the database is 2017-10-10 16:53:10.127. I'm in the UK and daylight savings are still in effect, so I'd expect the datetime to be rendered as 10 Oct 2017 17:53:10 - an hour ahead of the UTC value.

```
function foo() {
    $.get({
        url: '/foo/583',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('Raw:        ' + data.UpdatedAtUtc);

            var utc = moment.utc(data.UpdatedAtUtc);
            console.log('Moment UTC: ' + utc.format('DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
            console.log('Moment Local:' + utc.local().format('DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
        }
    });
}
```

The console output from this function is as follows:

```
Raw:          /Date(1507650790127)/
Moment UTC:   10 Oct 2017 15:53:10
Moment Local: 10 Oct 2017 16:53:10
```

Using [this online converter](https://www.freeformatter.com/epoch-timestamp-to-date-converter.html), I've confirmed that the raw datetime value in the JSON represents my UTC value (10/10/2017, 4:53:10 PM UTC), so I'm happy that the MVC back-end is correctly converting the UTC value without messing with time zones.

The value reported by the debugger on the client side is correct "/Date(1507650790127)/", and this is the value that I'm passing to the **utc()** method provided by moment.js with the understanding that it will interpret this as a UTC datetime value.

The [documentation](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/local-utc-zone/) for the **utc()** method states that:

> If you wish to interact with the date as a UTC date, use moment.utc:
>
> > moment.utc('2016-01-01T23:35:01');

so I *presume* that I'm using it correctly. The output from my tests, however, indicate that the datetime value is being treated as a local time, since the formatted output from the **utc()** method has shaved an hour off of the time, writing it to the console as 15:53 instead of 16:53

How do I initialise moment.js with the /Date()/ string correctly?

Comment: Please note that `1507650790127` is `10 October 2017 15:53:10.127 UTC` (see https://www.epochconverter.com), so I think that your code is fine.

Comment: The online converter that you're using is showing the _local_ representation of that timestamp (for me, GMT+2, it's showing 5:53PM).

Comment: Looks like I chose the wrong online converter then! No wonder I've been going around in circles! Looks like the culprit may well be MVC's Controller.JSON() method then if it's taking my UTC date value and converting it to local time before converting to /Date()/. Awesome :(/ Thanks to you both for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to VincencoC and robertklep for pointing out that the value being passed from my MVC back-end was the problem - moment.js is working just fine.

It turns out that the Controller.JSON() method was assuming that my dates are in the local timezone and was converting them from local to UTC before serializing to JSON.

In order to work around this, I've added a new class to the MVC project to provide custom JSON serialization using the Newtonsoft JSON.Net library from NuGet:

```
public class JsonNetResult : JsonResult
{
    private readonly string _json;

    public JsonNetResult(object data, JsonRequestBehavior behavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
    {
        _json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.None, new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" });
        JsonRequestBehavior = behavior;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = "application/json";
        response.Write(_json);
    }
}
```

In order to use the class, I've updated the relevant actions to return a JsonNetResult instead of a JsonResult and changed the return value as shown here:

```
public JsonNetResult AuditTrail(int id)
{
    var data = GetAuditData(id);

    //return this.Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    return new JsonNetResult(data);
}
```

This now formats all my DateTimes in "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss" format instead of /Date()/ and doesn't do time-zone conversion in the process.